# In how many ways can 9 Calculus and 3 Data Management books be arranged so that a)The three are not together b)There is a DM book at each end

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I already tried to answer the a) with indirect reasoning, putting the 3 Data Management books together and subtracting from the total. But the answer key says that the answer is 210 and my result is nowhere near that, I’m doing:

> DM DM DM + 9 = 10! - > 12! - 10!*3!

Can someone please explain why isn’t it working and explain the logic? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect they're considering the Calculus books to be indistinguishable and the Data Management books to be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Robert Shore mentions in his comment, books of a particular type (calculus/DM) are probably being considered as indistinguishable.

The relevant calculation here is instead $${12\choose3}-{10\choose1}=220-10=210$$

where we choose $3$ of $12$ positions to belong to DM books for the total case and subtract $10\choose1$ for the case where they all are together (choose $1$ out of $10$ positions for the 3 DM books to be placed together).

---

Part (b) can be solved by considering that we can place $x$ calculus books between the first and middle DM book and $(9-x)$ calculus books between the middle and last DM book. $x$ can take the values $0,1,2...9$ ($10$ different values) and thus the answer here is $10$ different arrangements.